# To get identity value in Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an entity `Task`, its domain class is

```
public class Task
{
    public long TaskId { get; set; }
    // blah blah
}
public DbSet<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
```

I hope that `TaskId` is the primary key and Auto-increment. Therefore we have

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Task>().Property(x => x.TaskId).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity).IsRequired();
    }
```

Now I add the data to db

```
    public bool AddTaskTable(int number,string[] params)
    {
        using (dbContext db = new dbContext())
        {
            var t = new Task { blah blah };
            db.Tasks.Add(t);
            try
            {
                db.SaveChanges();
                return true;
            }
```

What I want to is to retrieve the `TaskId` generated by the system for future use. For example, it is a foreign key I want to use it in another entity. How to get the value?

Comment: I use Guid, then add the attribute property `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]`

Comment: EF also has some rules so that you don't necessarily need the DatabaseGeneratedAttribute, although it won't hurt anything.

Comment: As an aside, I'd be a bit wary of naming a class Task because of the ambiguity with asynchronous tasks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think, when you do:

`db.SaveChanges();`

The actual model is changed, and the Id added. So if you read the model after the save it will show the updated Id that was generated.

Drawing on other answers in this chain this is very pertinent to my answer and is an explanation to my implementation:

EF creates POCO(Plain Old CLR Objects) domain models. Your entity model is not disposed, but it is in-memory. Your new task T is already in in-memory, so as soon as SaveChanges method called successfully, your object contains auto-generated ID as well.

This is my repository implementation:

```
public T Create<T>(T entity) where T : class
        {
            var newEntry = _dbContext.Set<T>().Add(entity);

            _dbContext.SaveChanges();

            return newEntry;
        }
```

Here, the entity is saved, and returned back with the new Id.

In your implementation do this:

```
public bool AddTaskTable(int number,string[] params)
    {
        using (dbContext db = new dbContext())
        {
            var t = new Task { blah blah };
            var dbTask = db.Tasks.Add(t);
            try
            {
                db.SaveChanges();

               // task id
               dbTask.taskId;

                return true;
            }
```

Answer (score 3):

The `TaskId` property should be filled on the entity after you save changes.

If you need it before you save changes (not the actual Id, but need to use this object as a foreign key property) you will need to use the navigational properties, and model your relationships.

Answer (score 0):

i think u can retrieve the `TaskId` while adding the Task something like :

```
public int AddTaskTable(int number,string[] params)
    {
        using (dbContext db = new dbContext())
        {
            var t = new Task { blah blah };
            db.Tasks.Add(t);
            try
            {
                db.SaveChanges();
                var newTaskId = dbContext
                                    .Tasks
                                    .OrderByDescending(x => x.TaskId)
                                    .FirstOrDefault().TaskId;
                return newTaskId;
             }
         }
    }
```

It will give u always exact value of `TaskId`.

Comment: Don't do this - you could easily have another thread add rows into the table in between the `db.SaveChanges()` call and the next line.  This would give you an invalid value for your object Id.  EntityFramework should automatically set the primary id when you save the entity.

Comment: I agree this is a bad way of doing it. It requires more db queries then is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

EF creates POCO(Plain Old CLR Objects) domain models. Your entity model is not disposed, but it is in-memory. Your new task T is already in in-memory, so as soon as *SaveChanges* method called successfully, your object contains auto-generated ID as well.

Comment: i don't see POCO explanation in your answer. It is concept which needs to explain along with the solution.

Comment: I will put your answer in mine then, to make sure that the accepted one has all the relevant information in.

Comment: Well your answer is also helpful. i see lot of threads which contains lot of answers lead to similar solution which most of the time becomes helpful resource :)